# How to use method reference when checking two strings are equal in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I'm new to Java 8 and just started learning.

This is my code snippet.

```
String name = "yoga";
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("yoga", "kani");
```

I did with lambda, It worked fine

```
Optional<String> resultSet = names.stream().filter(r->r.equals(name)).map(String::toUpperCase).findAny();
```

How to do the equals check with method reference. Is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name::equals`.

Answer (score 3):

`r->r.equals(name)` cannot be converted to a method reference because Java language doesn't support that. However, you can do a little trick: since `str1.equals(str2)` returns the same result as `str2.equals(str1)` (except for nulls, but this is not the case here), you can rewrite `r -> r.equals(name)` to `r -> name.equals(r)`. The new lambda is now convertible to a method reference:

```
Optional<String> resultSet = names
        .stream()
        .filter(name::equals)
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .findAny();
```